# Windows UAC - How to Handle the User Cancelling

Tags: c#, .net, windows, exception, uac

I need to spawn a process with elevated privileges which would cause a UAC prompt to pop up for the user:

```
using (process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Join(" ", arg1, arg2, arg3);
    process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    process.Start();
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that if the user selects 'no' in the UAC prompt, the process object will throw an exception stating that 'The operation was canceled by the user.' If the user selects no, then the parent process should just continue as normal (the spawned process is completely optional). Is there a better way of handling this scenario other than just catching the exception and doing nothing?

Comment: Use try/catch to catch the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What else would you want to do instead of catching the exception and doing nothing? That is the only thing that I can think about.

Comment: That's what I'm wondering. Perhaps there's some obscure way of handling the issue without exceptions that I'm not aware of (just to maintain good practices). If not, then I'll just catch and do nothing.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with catching exceptions. You just should know WHY they get thrown. If you don't know why, you probably don't know in which state your application will be after the exception and it's better to let your application crash (Maybe in a nice way).

If you know why you got the exception (like in this case) you can just catch it and HANDLE it. This keeps your application in a state you know and there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: To put this another way, since you're using a runtime (.NET) which is designed to use exceptions, you can't expect to avoid them - or at least not entirely.  If you don't want to use exceptions, use C and the Win32 API, or choose another language and runtime that suits you better.

Answer (score 3):

You need to catch the error and if you use a background worker you won't get any exception error. Nevertheless, It is still bad practice not to catch exceptions separately.

Here is how It's done:

```
try
{
    //your code here
        using (process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Join(" ", arg1, arg2, arg3);
                process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                process.Start();

            }
    //end code
}
catch(System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
{
//Do Something or Leave it empty to swallow the exception
}
```

Comment: This can be a better answer if you check `NativeErrorCode` of that `Win32Exception`, and compare to `1223`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299-